# Create scoped credential with pemanent SAS for BULK INSERT from blob storage to Azure Database

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

My application will write several records on a Azure SQL Database on a regular basis. I found that the most efficient way to do this was using BULK INSERT, so I was building a Blob Trigger function which would execute everytime a file is uploaded in my blob container to upload their contents into the database. I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15) that a scoped credential should be created in the database with a SAS from the blob storage account, however I understand SAS has expiration dates, so I guess I should have to update the scoped credential at some point. Is there a way to create a permanent credential so I don't have to update it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a function output binding instead to connect to the SQL Server? This would keep the function code simple.

See here for an example of how to achieve this : http://davidpallmann.blogspot.com/2019/02/new-sql-database-binding-for-azure.html

Comment: That example does not use a output binding

Comment: Sorry my bad. See here for how to set up an output binding for SQL server. It is pretty straightforward and removes all complexity from the developer : http://davidpallmann.blogspot.com/2019/02/new-sql-database-binding-for-azure.html